How does secure view hides underlying data? And how are the Snowflakes' internal optimizations are not possible?
Secure views are meant to hide the view's definition.
But they also hide underlying data and hence somehow lose the internal optimizations that are possible in non-secure views.
How does it hide underlying data?
Why does it lose the internal optimizations?
I tried to look at this section which says that a user might be able to infer that Purple color widget is present in the data with non-secure view.
Here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/views-secure#how-might-data-be-exposed-by-a-non-secure-view
SELECT *
FROM widgets_view
WHERE 1/iff(color = 'Purple', 0, 1) = 1;

Thanks!

This is clearly explained later in the page that you link to (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/views-secure#using-secure-views-with-snowflake-access-control). Can you be more specific about what you don't understand, please?
